# Does IPv6 have similar concept of network mask?

Tags: subnet, ipv6

Does IPv6 have similar concept of network mask?

How does it represent a network?

In the output of `ifconfig`, does `prefixlen 128` represent a network mask?

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1552397  bytes 88437726 (88.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1552397  bytes 88437726 (88.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 10):

IPv6 uses network masks exactly the same way as IPv4.  The only real difference is that they're much longer (128 bits).  IPv6 uses the slash notation exclusively (no dotted decimal), so masks range from /0 to /128.

Becasue of the much larger address space, it's rare to see a mask length longer than /64.

Comment: Thanks. IPv6 address itself is 128 bits, If a network mask is 128 bits, does that mean the network only has one host? See my update for an example

Comment: Yes.  It's the equivalent of using a /32 for IPv4.

Comment: Do you mean prefixlen 128 represent a network mask? How can the network for prefixlen 128 (only one host) be so different from the network for the IPv4 network mask 255.0.0.0 (have many hosts) for the same network interface? Do they represent the same network?

Comment: Yes,  prefixlen is the same as network mask, although the term "prefix length" is preferred.

Comment: How can the network for prefixlen 128 (only one host) be so different from the network for the IPv4 network mask 255.0.0.0 (have many hosts) for the same network interface? Do they represent the same network?

Comment: That's not correct. A /128 for IPv6 is functionally the same as a /32 or 255.255.255.255 for IPv4.   255.0.0.0 is written as /8

Comment: Then why are `netmask 255.0.0.0` and `prefixlen 128` both assigned to the same network interface `lo`, if they represent different networks?

Comment: They are different addressing schemes, so there is no correspondence between them.  Also, the IPv4 loopback address, 127.0.0.1, is always written with a /8 mask (per the RFC), even though technically, there's only one host.

Comment: Per RFC 5735, in IPv4 *any* address in 127.0.0.0/8 can be a loopback address; there is RFC requirement that 127.0.0.1/32 be *the* loopback address.

Comment: It's rare to see longer than /64 except for the specific case of /128.

Comment: @chrylis, per _[RFC 6164, Using 127-Bit IPv6 Prefixes on Inter-Router Links](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6164)_,point-to-point links can (and probably should, in the absence of verified proof against a ping pong attack) use `/127`. Apparently, even big vendors that claim immunity to ping pong attacks can still be vulnerable.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for the link. I haven't encountered this in the wild.

Comment: @chrylis, we have adopted `/127` for all our point-to-point links, except for the connection to the telcos, where they require `/126` because of the way IPv4 used `/30`. We have tried, and tried to explain things to them, but they will not listen, so we are careful to test in the lab that any devices we use to connect to them really are immune to the ping pong attack.

Answer (score 3):

Your example contains a netmask. It is however not specified as a bitmask since this would be very long and confusing but as the length of one-bits in the mask. This is called the prefix length and is given either separately (as in your example) or with slash notation:

```
inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128
```

This is equivalent to `::1/128` would look like

```
ip.  0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
mask ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
```

While the mask is pretty much the same as in v4 there are some conventions around assignment. For having a good notation the prefixlen is typically given in multiple of four and /64 is regarded as a single LAN (also required by some autoconf technologies).

If you think of ipv6 it is a good idea to regard the prefix always as dynamic and allow renumbering, then you are good to go.